# Can i add API controller in Areas in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can i add api controller in areas in mvc.and access it

Comment: Have you tried to enable "Show all files" in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer and include the copied files and folders?

Answer (score 3):

**Web API does not have any concept of areas which is a standard "MVC" feature.**

You can place web API controllers anywhere in your solution and they will simply work regardless of their location in the solution structure.

There is no folder based convention for WEB API controllers, always remember that WEB API controllers are different to standard MVC controllers in this way.

You can add your MVC controllers to any folder you like (including those folders relating to your areas).

Answer (score 1):

Its simple. Create yours MVC project. You can add your api controller to your controller by right click on controllers folder select add you will find many option choose Web API Controller class. I think this will help

Comment: Web API does not support areas.

Comment: Ya its true. We can add API Controller anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a API controller  anywhere (in an area) but to access it, by default, always use the same code

```
 http://www.yourapp.com/api/yourcontroller
```

It didn't work when I tried `http://www.yourapp.com/MYAREA/api/yourcontroller`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Easily

1-Create a folder named Api (for example) inside your area's controller folder

2- Create an Api controller inside Api folder

3- Go to your [AreaName] AreaRegistration.cs File

4-Add new route into RegisterArea method

ex:

context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "MyAreaApi",
             routeTemplate: "MyAreaApi/api/{controller}/{id}",
             defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
         )

5-Finish